# French --> English "À leur tour"

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, translation, french

I'm trying to translate the french "À leur tour" into English.
I believe Literal translation would give something like this : "It was now their turn to"

The sentence is the following : "They introduced me, "à leur tour", to their friends."

For example, someone introduced me to his friends, and these friends then introduced me to their friends.

I can't seem to find something decent in the Dictionary.

Comment: Please explain a little more about the context in which the French phrase is used. Is it their turn  because you introduced them to your friends already?

Comment: No, someone introduced me to his friends, and these friends then introduced me to their friends. Hope it's more clear

Answer (score 7):

I think

> "I met them today, and **they in turn** introduced me to their friends."

or a little more formally (as suggested by StoneyB in the comments)

> "I met them today, and **they in their turn** introduced me to their friends."
>   "I met them today, and **in turn they** introduced me to their friends."

would capture the same meaning. The idiom "[in turn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+turn)" in English means "in the proper/appropriate sequence" and there is also "out of turn" meaning the opposite. For example, "I apologized for speaking out of turn."

Also, as P.E. Dant mentioned in the comments, "[For their part](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+part)" might work as well, but it's not something I use naturally.

> "I met them today, and they, **for their part**, introduced me to their friends."

Comment: +1 Also, "And they in their turn" or "and in their turn they", which are a tad more formal.

Comment: @ColleenV I remember asking my pal about this exact expression in Paris ten years ago. She said, sans hésiter, "For their part." +1

Comment: @P.E.Dant I incorporated your comment into my answer because comments are ephemeral, but I think "For ones part" could be an answer in its own right after trying to go into more detail about it. If you want to write an answer, let me know and I'll revert the edit to my answer so folks don't get confused.

Comment: @ColleenV Thinking back, when she answered, _à leur tour_ was used in a slightly different context. We were talking politics, and the sense was that some pols had compromised on something, and their opposite numbers were expected to do the same _à leur tour_ - to reciprocate. This may be significant, but perhaps not to a student of English, so I'm not sure it warrants a separate answer...